# Аn error occurred while applying security settings authenticated users is not a valid - NodeJs

Tags: node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу установить NodeJs. Возникает такая ошибка. Что делать ? Нигде решения найти не могу

Comment: Скорее всего проблемы на серверах ноды. Тоже не могу поставить, подобная ситуация.

Comment: Подтверждаю, ошибка есть такая! Удалил старую версию, решил обновить, выдаёт то же самое. Переустановил систему начисто, думая на конфликт чего либо, но проблема осталась.

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1301146), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1301435), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1301601)

Answer (score 3):

Скачал предыдущую версию, все работает:
https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.1/node-v14.17.1-x64.msi

Подглядел здесь: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/516315/erro-na-instalação-do-node-js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/516315/erro-na-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Та же самая проблема. Поискала на форумах, некоторые предлагают решение

1. Добавить новую группу (в lusrmgr.msc) с именем "User" и добавить ваш профиль в эту группу
2. Запустить cmd от имени администратора и выполнить команды:

- net localgroup Users /add
- net localgroup Users <user_name> /add

Одно и то же, способы разные. Попробуйте. может Вам поможет

Им помогло. Мне нет. Ничего не работает

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему не решил. По итогу просто скачала rar файл с NodeJs и вручную вписал путь к NodeJs (path)

Answer (score 1):

Похоже он не может создать папку nodejs, создал ее вручную потом указал путь при установке и вроде все прошло.

Answer (score 1):

Была такая проблема, помогло следующее:

1. Запустить cmd от имени администратора;

Далее вводим:

2. net localgroup Users /add;
3. net localgroup /add “Authenticated Users”

Вот тут есть ещё способы https://exerror.com/an-error-occurred-while-applying-security-settings-authenticated-users-is-not-a-valid-user-or-group-in-nodejs-windows/