# Не устанавливается Node.JS в Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, install

> An error occured while applying security settings. Authenticated Users is not a valid user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a problem connecting to domain controller on the network. Check your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install

Comment: См. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224 — там есть несколько вариантов решения до выпуска новой исправленной версии.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Причина предоставлена ​​@JIT Solution

Для решения: добавьте недостающую группу.

Откройте инструмент «Управление компьютером».
Откройте дерево «Локальные пользователи и группа».
Откройте папку «Группы» и найдите профиль с именем «Прошедшие проверку», он должен отсутствовать.
Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши папку "Группы" и выберите "Новая группа".  Введите « Authenticated Users» (с учетом регистра) в качестве имени новой группы и выберите «Создать».