# Как исправить ошибку при установке node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

Во время установки node.js возвращается ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"An error occurred while applying security settings.
Authentcated Users is not a valid user or group. This
could be a problem with the package, or a problem
connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check
your network connecton and dick Retry, or Cancel to
end the install."

Отключил UAC, запустил установку, но ошибка появилась снова.
С интернет подключением все в порядке. Брандмауэр не ругался.

Перепробовал разные версии установщиков (node-v14.17.2-x64.msi, node-v16.4.1-x64.msi), но ошибка повторяется.

Comment: Установите предыдущий релиз - в последнем накосячили с локализованными ОС.

Comment: Подробности проблемы и варианты временных решений: см. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224

Answer (score 0):

При установке предыдущей версии [14.17.1](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.1/) ошибка не вылетает.